# Read a text file with nested dictionary and convert to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The text file contains nested dictionary and the sample data have columns as below:

```py
{
    'tradable': True,
    'mode': 'full',
    'instrument_token': 70401,
    'last_price': 784.35,
    'last_quantity': 10,
    'average_price': 0.0,
    'volume': 2301,
    'buy_quantity': 22208,
    'sell_quantity': 54655,
    'ohlc': {
        'open': 788.9,
        'high': 789.5,
        'low': 772.8,
        'close': 784.35
    },
    'change': 0.0,
    'last_trade_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 4, 15, 50, 29),
    'oi': 0,
    'oi_day_high': 0,
    'oi_day_low': 0,
    'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 9, 7),
    'depth': {
        'buy': [{
                'quantity': 43,
                'price': 807.9,
                'orders': 1
            }, {
                'quantity': 65,
                'price': 795.0,
                'orders': 2
            }, {
                'quantity': 55,
                'price': 791.0,
                'orders': 1
            }, {
                'quantity': 25,
                'price': 790.1,
                'orders': 1
            }, {
                'quantity': 507,
                'price': 42949670.41,
                'orders': 12
            }
        ],
        'sell': [{
                'quantity': 114,
                'price': 705.95,
                'orders': 1
            }, {
                'quantity': 20,
                'price': 760.85,
                'orders': 1
            }, {
                'quantity': 1,
                'price': 778.0,
                'orders': 1
            }, {
                'quantity': 1,
                'price': 779.0,
                'orders': 1
            }, {
                'quantity': 176,
                'price': 42949670.41,
                'orders': 6
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to read the text file and convert the data to csv file with field as below:

```
columns = 
[
'tradable', 
'mode', 
'instrument_token', 
'last_price',
'last_quantity', 
'average_price', 
'volume',
'buy_quantity',
'sell_quantity', 

'ohlc.open',
'ohlc.high',
'ohlc.low',
'ohlc.close',

'change', 
'last_trade_time', 
'oi', 
'oi_day_high', 
'oi_day_low', 
'timestamp',

'depth.buy.quantity1',
'depth.buy.price1',
'depth.buy.orders1',
'depth.buy.quantity2',
'depth.buy.price2',
'depth.buy.orders2',
'depth.buy.quantity3',
'depth.buy.price3',
'depth.buy.orders3',
'depth.buy.quantity4',
'depth.buy.price4',
'depth.buy.orders4',
'depth.buy.quantity5',
'depth.buy.price5',
'depth.buy.orders5',

'depth.sell.quantity1',
'depth.sell.price1',
'depth.sell.orders1',
'depth.sell.quantity2',
'depth.sell.price2',
'depth.sell.orders2',
'depth.sell.quantity3',
'depth.sell.price3',
'depth.sell.orders3',
'depth.sell.quantity4',
'depth.sell.price4',
'depth.sell.orders4',
'depth.sell.quantity5',
'depth.sell.price5',
'depth.sell.orders5',
]
```

A sample file of text file is attached here for reference:
[Data.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gB9CQ9tf3V4mebmtVcKRD8EEbpVNXgMn)

The nested columns in **olhc** to be rename as olhc.open, olhc.close etc and **depth** to be converted as depth.**buy**.quantity1, depth.**buy**.price1, depth.**buy**.orders1, for buy portion and depth.**sell**.quantity1, depth.**sell**.price1, depth.**sell**.orders1 etc for sell portion. Any help.

Comment: Hi! You should be more specific in your question in terms of what you have tried and what you are having trouble achieving

Comment: Sir, I am bit new to python. In my example I am not able to understand how to move the line data to pandas and what line separator to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a mixture of two both :-

```
from flatten_json import flatten
import datetime
import pandas as pd

with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    lists = list(map(eval,file.readlines()))


final = []

def append_final(x):
    global final
    final.append(x)

def parse_list(l):
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item,dict):
            result=flatten(item,'.')
            append_final(result)
        elif isinstance(item,list):
            parse_list(item)

parse_list(lists)

for f in final:
    for d,dd in f.items():
        print(d,":",dd)
```

Output:

```
tradable : True
mode : full
instrument_token : 70401
last_price : 784.35
last_quantity : 10
average_price : 0.0
volume : 2301
buy_quantity : 22208
sell_quantity : 54655
ohlc.open : 788.9
ohlc.high : 789.5
ohlc.low : 772.8
ohlc.close : 784.35
change : 0.0
last_trade_time : 2019-04-04 15:50:29
oi : 0
oi_day_high : 0
oi_day_low : 0
timestamp : 2019-04-05 09:07:00
depth.buy.0.quantity : 43
depth.buy.0.price : 807.9
depth.buy.0.orders : 1
depth.buy.1.quantity : 65
depth.buy.1.price : 795.0
depth.buy.1.orders : 2
depth.buy.2.quantity : 55
depth.buy.2.price : 791.0
depth.buy.2.orders : 1
depth.buy.3.quantity : 25
depth.buy.3.price : 790.1
depth.buy.3.orders : 1
depth.buy.4.quantity : 507
depth.buy.4.price : 42949670.41
depth.buy.4.orders : 12
depth.sell.0.quantity : 114
depth.sell.0.price : 705.95
depth.sell.0.orders : 1
depth.sell.1.quantity : 20
depth.sell.1.price : 760.85
depth.sell.1.orders : 1
depth.sell.2.quantity : 1
depth.sell.2.price : 778.0
depth.sell.2.orders : 1
depth.sell.3.quantity : 1
depth.sell.3.price : 779.0
depth.sell.3.orders : 1
depth.sell.4.quantity : 176
depth.sell.4.price : 42949670.41
depth.sell.4.orders : 6
tradable : True
mode : full
instrument_token : 784129
last_price : 187.2
last_quantity : 1
average_price : 0.0
volume : 7173
buy_quantity : 98533
sell_quantity : 108870
ohlc.open : 188.6
ohlc.high : 189.15
ohlc.low : 183.4
ohlc.close : 187.2
change : 0.0
last_trade_time : 2019-04-04 15:58:40
oi : 0
oi_day_high : 0
oi_day_low : 0
timestamp : 2019-04-05 09:07:00
depth.buy.0.quantity : 2
depth.buy.0.price : 200.0
depth.buy.0.orders : 2
depth.buy.1.quantity : 1
depth.buy.1.price : 199.95
depth.buy.1.orders : 1
depth.buy.2.quantity : 1
depth.buy.2.price : 199.9
depth.buy.2.orders : 1
depth.buy.3.quantity : 1
depth.buy.3.price : 199.85
depth.buy.3.orders : 1
depth.buy.4.quantity : 1901
depth.buy.4.price : 42949670.41
depth.buy.4.orders : 28
depth.sell.0.quantity : 110
depth.sell.0.price : 179.0
depth.sell.0.orders : 1
depth.sell.1.quantity : 50
depth.sell.1.price : 180.0
depth.sell.1.orders : 1
depth.sell.2.quantity : 1
depth.sell.2.price : 181.0
depth.sell.2.orders : 1
depth.sell.3.quantity : 150
depth.sell.3.price : 185.0
depth.sell.3.orders : 1
depth.sell.4.quantity : 421
depth.sell.4.price : 42949670.41
depth.sell.4.orders : 14
tradable : True
mode : full
instrument_token : 215553
last_price : 148.9
last_quantity : 247
average_price : 0.0
volume : 11940
buy_quantity : 106132
sell_quantity : 259400
ohlc.open : 149.8
ohlc.high : 150.75
ohlc.low : 146.5
ohlc.close : 148.9
change : 0.0
last_trade_time : 2019-04-04 15:59:02
oi : 0
oi_day_high : 0
oi_day_low : 0
timestamp : 2019-04-05 09:07:00
depth.buy.0.quantity : 100
depth.buy.0.price : 158.0
depth.buy.0.orders : 1
.....
```

Comment: Yes, It's a good thing that you mixed both of our answers. At the end of the day, the OP accepts the answer which he feels right. **Writing more than one answer to the same question will not get you more reputation and when you used someone else answers or you referred some part of the internet to answer PLEASE give credit to them and attach hyperlinks so that the OP can gain more info about it.** Have a Good Day Mr. **mrHOT**

Comment: @Justice_Lords
Thanks for this lesson, I am also a beginner as you can see, by the next time, I will stick to your guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to your problem :

```
import datetime


with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    lists = list(map(eval,file.readlines()))


final = []

def append_final(x):
    global final
    last = 0
    for name in final:
        if x in name:
            num = ''
            for n in reversed(name):
                if str.isdigit(n):
                    num = n + num
            if num and int(num)>last:
                last = int(num)

    final.append(x+str(last+1))

def parse_dict(d,base=''):
    for key in d.keys():
        if base:
            new_base = base + "." + key
        else:
            new_base = key
        append_final(new_base)
        if isinstance(d[key],dict): 
            parse_dict(d[key],new_base)
        elif isinstance(d[key], list):
            parse_list(d[key],new_base)

def parse_list(l,base=''):
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            parse_dict(item,base)
        elif isinstance(item, str):
            if base:
                new_base = base+ "." + item
            else:
                new_base = item
            append_final(new_base)


for l in lists:
    parse_list(l)

final.sort()

print(final)
```

This may take a while to process all your keys, have patience.
Do some modifications to it as per your needs. :)

Comment: Sir, this code takes really very very long time for 6MB file.

Comment: You need to do some modifications for best output, It's just a path to what you need, not the exact solution, the time taken is from the function 'append_final', use regular expressions to minimize that, it will short it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
from flatten_json import flatten
result=flatten(your_dict,'.')
data=pd.DataFrame(result,index=[0])
```

This should do your work.

Reference:-

1. [flatten_json()](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten)

Comment: Sir, my input is a text file hence giving Error: **flatten requires a dictionary input**

Comment: @Rohit You can convert text to dict from text file using `eval()` as in `your_dict=eval(open("data.txt", "r").read())`